# Python 3.x tkinter - How can I duplicate the same sprite on the canvas in random locations?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

In my code (which will be at the end of the long description) I have made a tkinter canvas game. So far, the sprite on the canvas called "player" moves towards the mouse. When the sprite "player"'s coordinates are close enough to the sprite "food"'s coordinates then the food is deleted from the canvas and then created again in another random location. This also increases the size of the sprite "player" by 1 (by adding 1 to the x1 and y1 coordinates).

But my issue is that without some very strange results I cannot seem to be able to create any more than 1 stable "food" sprite. Ideally I'd like to be able to duplicate infinitely until my CPU overheats... but I'll settle for 10 sprites (But then need to be identical). This is so that the "player" sprite has much more food to eat.

```
import random
from tkinter import *
import math
import time

class Cells():

    def __init__(self):
        #Variables
        self.master = Tk()
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.master, width=1000,height=800)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.player_colours = ['blue','red','orange','green','purple','yellow']
        self.random_int = random.randint(0,5)
        self.random_colour = self.player_colours[self.random_int]
        self.random_food_int = random.randint(0,5)
        self.random_food_colour = self.player_colours[self.random_food_int]
        self.tick_intervals = 10
        #Coords
        self.x0 = 500
        self.y0 = 400
        self.x1 = 530 
        self.y1 = 430
        self.rx0 = random.randint(100,900)
        self.ry0 = random.randint(100,700)
        self.rx1 = self.rx0 + 20
        self.ry1 = self.ry0 + 20
        self.rx0_2 = random.randint(100,900)
        self.ry0_2 = random.randint(100,700)
        self.rx1_2 = self.rx0_2 + 20
        self.ry1_2 = self.ry0_2 + 20
        self.player_size = self.x1 - self.x0
        self.player_coords = [self.x0, ",", self.y0]
        #Sprites
        self.speed = (self.x0 - self.x1) / 10
        self.reverse = self.speed - self.speed - self.speed
        self.food = self.canvas.create_oval(self.rx0,self.ry0,self.rx1,self.ry1,fill=self.random_food_colour)
        self.player = self.canvas.create_oval(self.x0,self.y0,self.x1,self.y1, fill=self.random_colour)
        self.player_coords_text_x = self.canvas.create_text(50,10,text=self.x0)
        self.player_coords_text_y = self.canvas.create_text(100,10,text=self.y0)
        self.food_coords_text_x = self.canvas.create_text(50,10,text=self.rx0_2)
        self.food_coords_text_y = self.canvas.create_text(100,10,text=self.ry0_2)
        self.player_text = self.canvas.create_text(self.x0,self.y0,text=self.player_size)
        self.food_count = 1
        self.move()
        self.master.mainloop()
    def move(self):
        self.canvas.delete(self.player_coords_text_x)
        self.canvas.delete(self.player_coords_text_y)
        self.player_coords_text_x = self.canvas.create_text(50,10,text=self.x0)
        self.player_coords_text_y = self.canvas.create_text(100,10,text=self.y0)

        self.canvas.delete(self.food_coords_text_x)
        self.canvas.delete(self.food_coords_text_y)
        self.food_coords_text_x = self.canvas.create_text(50,50,text=self.rx0_2)
        self.food_coords_text_y = self.canvas.create_text(100,50,text=self.ry0_2)


        self.is_food = True
        #mouse variables
        x = self.canvas.winfo_pointerx()-self.canvas.winfo_rootx()
        y = self.canvas.winfo_pointery()-self.canvas.winfo_rooty()
        self.mousex0 = x - 10
        self.mousey0 = y - 10
        self.mousex1 = x + 10
        self.mousey1 = y + 10
        #sprite variables
        self.player_center_x = self.x0 + ((self.x1 - self.x0) / 3)
        self.player_center_y = self.y0 + ((self.x1 - self.x0) / 3)

        self.canvas.delete(self.player_text)
        self.player_text = self.canvas.create_text(self.player_center_x,self.player_center_y,text=self.player_size)
        #bounderies
        if self.player_center_x < 20:
            self.x0 -=self.speed
            self.x1 -=self.speed
        elif self.player_center_x > 980:
            self.x0 += self.speed
            self.x1 += self.speed
        if self.player_center_y < 20:
            self.y0 -= self.speed
            self.y1 -= self.speed
        elif self.player_center_y > 780:
            self.y0 += self.speed
            self.y1 += self.speed
        #following the mouse
        if self.player_center_x < self.mousex0:
            self.x0 -= self.speed
            self.x1 -= self.speed
        elif self.player_center_x > self.mousex0:
            self.x0 += self.speed
            self.x1 += self.speed
        if self.player_center_y < self.mousey0:
            self.y0 -= self.speed
            self.y1 -= self.speed
        elif self.player_center_y > self.mousey0:
            self.y0 += self.speed
            self.y1 += self.speed
        #eating the food
        if self.is_food == True:
            if self.x0 < self.rx0 and (self.rx0 - self.x0) <= self.player_size:
                if self.y0 < self.ry0 and (self.ry0 - self.y0) <= self.player_size:
                    self.canvas.delete(self.food)
                    self.player_size += 1
                    self.x1 += 1
                    self.y1 += 1
                    self.is_food = False
            if self.x0 > self.rx0 and (self.x0 - self.rx0) <= self.player_size:
                if self.y0 < self.ry0 and (self.ry0 - self.y0) <= self.player_size:
                    self.canvas.delete(self.food)
                    self.player_size += 1
                    self.x1 += 1
                    self.y1 += 1
                    self.is_food = False
            if self.x0 > self.rx0 and (self.x0 - self.rx0) <= self.player_size:
                if self.y0 > self.ry0 and (self.y0 - self.ry0) <= self.player_size:
                    self.canvas.delete(self.food)
                    self.player_size += 1
                    self.x1 += 1
                    self.y1 += 1
                    self.is_food = False
            if self.x0 < self.rx0 and (self.rx0 - self.x0) <= self.player_size:
                if self.y0 > self.ry0 and (self.y0 - self.ry0) <= self.player_size:
                    self.canvas.delete(self.food)
                    self.player_size += 1
                    self.x1 += 1
                    self.y1 += 1
                    self.is_food = False
        if self.is_food == True:
            if self.player_center_x < self.rx0_2 and (self.rx0_2 - self.player_center_x) <= self.player_size:
                if self.player_center_y < self.ry0_2 and (self.ry0_2 - self.player_center_y) <= self.player_size:
                   self.canvas.delete(self.food)
                   self.player_size += 1
                   self.x1 += 1
                   self.y1 += 1
                    self.is_food = False
            elif self.player_center_x > self.rx0_2 and (self.player_center_x - self.rx0_2) <= self.player_size:
               if self.player_center_y < self.ry0_2 and (self.ry0_2 - self.player_center_y) <= self.player_size:
                    self.canvas.delete(self.food)
                    self.player_size += 1
                    self.x1 += 1
                    self.y1 += 1
                    self.is_food = False
            elif self.player_center_x > self.rx0_2 and (self.player_center_x - self.rx0_2) <= self.player_size:
                if self.player_center_y > self.ry0_2 and (self.ry0_2 + self.player_center_y) <= self.player_size:
                    self.canvas.delete(self.food)
                    self.player_size += 1
                    self.x1 += 1
                    self.y1 += 1
                    self.is_food = False
            elif self.player_center_x < self.rx0_2 and (self.player_center_x + self.rx0_2) <= self.player_size:
                if self.player_center_y > self.ry0_2 and (self.ry0_2 + self.player_center_y) <= self.player_size:
                    self.canvas.delete(self.food)
                    self.player_size += 1
                    self.x1 += 1
                    self.y1 += 1
                    self.is_food = False

        if self.is_food == False:
            self.rx0_2 = random.randint(100,900)
            self.ry0_2 = random.randint(100,700)
            self.rx1_2 = self.rx0_2 + 20
            self.ry1_2 = self.ry0_2 + 20
            self.food = self.canvas.create_oval(self.rx0_2,self.ry0_2,self.rx1_2,self.ry1_2,fill=self.random_food_colour)
            self.is_food = True
```

This Guys is where my original idea for how to duplicate the same sprite comes from. But if you run it yourselves you will see that the results are... questionable.
Please help me make this work guys.

```
        #if self.food_count <= 10:
            #self.food = self.canvas.create_oval(self.rx0_2,self.ry0_2,self.rx1_2,self.ry1_2,fill=self.random_food_colour)
            #self.food_count += 1

        #loop
        self.canvas.coords(self.player,self.x0,self.y0,self.x1,self.y1)
        self.canvas.after(self.tick_intervals,self.move)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Cells()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer below:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.label = []
        self.text = []
        self.root.geometry("500x500")
        self.canvas = Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
        self.button = Button(self.canvas, text="Ok", command=self.random)
        self.canvas.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
        self.button.pack()
    def random(self):
        self.label.append(Label(self.canvas, text="text"))
        for i in self.label:
            self.text.append(self.canvas.create_window(random.randrange(500), random.randrange(500), window=i))
    
root = Tk()
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

In the above we create two `list`s `label` and `text`.

Every time the `button` is pushed we create a new `label` and store it in the list `label`. We then iterate on the `list` `label` and create a new `canvas` window for every element in the list, storing these windows inside `text` for later use.

This will allow you to continue producing food objects until your CPU overheats.

---

Your question boils down to "How can I randomise the position of multiple objects in a canvas?"